# Cannot update Stock Module in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When I use the shell to update the modules, I'm getting these errors:

> 2015-05-11 21:06:26,987 9822 ERROR db openerp.modules.graph: module purchase: Unmet dependencies: stock_account
>   2015-05-11 21:06:26,987 9822 ERROR db openerp.modules.graph: module portal_stock: Unmet dependencies: sale_stock
>   2015-05-11 21:06:26,988 9822 ERROR db openerp.modules.graph: module warning: Unmet dependencies: sale_stock, purchase
>   2015-05-11 21:06:26,988 9822 ERROR db openerp.modules.graph: module sale_stock: Unmet dependencies: stock_account
>   2015-05-11 21:06:26,988 9822 ERROR db openerp.modules.graph: module stock_account: Unmet dependencies: stock

The problem was changing privileges. How can I restore them?

Answer (score 2):

This message comes only when  you modify the _depends from  **__openerp__.py** file  of base module in odoo.

You should set the depended module which are currently require for stock module and update all the module via terminal with your database name.
then this message will be disappeared automatically.